# Exception while wrting dataframe to Kafka using pyspark

Tags: kubernetes, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a dataframe new_df and load the DataFrame to Kafka using pyspark. However, I'm getting few exception. Couldn't figure what exactly is the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
>>> dict = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},{'name': 'Again', 'age': 2}]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(dict)

>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
>>> timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> type(timestamp)
<class 'str'>

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,unix_timestamp
>>> timestamp
'2017-08-02 16:16:14'
>>> new_df = df.withColumn('time',unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
>>> new_df.show(truncate = False)
+---+-----+---------------------+
|age|name |time                 |
+---+-----+---------------------+
|1  |Alice|2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Again|2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
+---+-----+---------------------+
```

Now I'm trying to wrtie the dataframe to a Kafka topic

```
def writeToKafka(outputDF):
    outputDF.selectExpr("CAST(time AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
                .write \
                .format("kafka") \
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-svc:9092") \
                .option("topic", "test_topic") \
                .save()



writeToKafka(new_df)
```

Exceptions(picked from error):

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

Full Error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1811.save. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 8 in stage 76.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 8.0 in stage 76.0 (TID 110, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
> producer  at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:432)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:270)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$CachedKafkaProducer$$createKafkaProducer(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:67)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$$anon$1.load(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:46)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$$anon$1.load(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:43)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)   at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
> at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$.getOrCreate(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriteTask.execute(KafkaWriteTask.scala:44)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:87)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable
> bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:88)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:407)
> ... 31 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)     at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:980)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:978)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)    at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:978)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.write(KafkaWriter.scala:87)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:254)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:268)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
> producer  at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:432)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:270)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$CachedKafkaProducer$$createKafkaProducer(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:67)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$$anon$1.load(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:46)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$$anon$1.load(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:43)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)   at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
> at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
> at
> org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaProducer$.getOrCreate(CachedKafkaProducer.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriteTask.execute(KafkaWriteTask.scala:44)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:89)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:87)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> ... 1 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException:
> No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:88)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:407)
> ... 31 more

## Note:

I have 3 kafka brokers, 3 kafka zookeepers which are hosted on Kubernetes Cluster.

Comment: did you take a look to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969955/org-apache-kafka-common-kafkaexception-failed-to-construct-kafka-consumer

Comment: `No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers`... We cannot fix your networking issues, but have you tried any other Kafka client using the same address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New code:

```
def writeToKafka(outputDF):
    outputDF.selectExpr("CAST(time AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
                .write \
                .format("kafka") \
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-svc.test_namespace:9092") \
                .option("topic", "test_topic") \
                .save()
```

The kafka brokers are on another namespace in kubernetes cluster. And, my jupyter notebook was on another namespace.

Once I tried with "kafka_service.namespace:portno" for the kafka.bootstrap.servers (i.e.,`kafka-svc.test_namespace:9092` ), it worked

> ```
> kafka-svc - is the kafka service name.
> test_namespace - is the name of the namespace where kafka brokers are hosted
> ```